# CSS clearfix alternative for children with fixed position

Tags: html, css

I know that **clearfix** is a way to combat the zero-height container problem for floated elements.

But, I am wondering if there's any clearfix-like way for fixed elements?

I am stuck and getting anywhere from clearfix method.

```css
.navbar-float {
  background-color: #adadad;
  float: left;
}

.navbar-fixed {
  background-color: #dadada;
  position: fixed;
}

div.clearfix {
  border: 1px solid #adadad;
  padding: 4px;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear:both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <nav class="navbar-float">
    Float
  </nav>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="clearfix">
  <nav class="navbar-fixed">
    Fixed
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: `Fixed` is like `absolute` intended to not influence parent or sibling containers. If you don't want this behavior go for another layout option.

Comment: Fixed positioning is like absolute but with the particularity that appends from document, not from parent. In addition of @NicoO

Comment: @NicoO Say if I have a header with dynamic height depends on the viewport. Does it mean that I have to use css media queries for my content to each viewport to leave some space on header so they're not overlapping each others? Or there's another simple way to do this.

Comment: @choz there are a lot of ways to solve such problems. It depends on the desired implementation and requirements what solution will be the best match. You could create a [mcev](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) describing your problem and maybe ask this as a new question. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr; no.**

The reason for this not working or going to work with this setup is because of the way the document *flows* - when you add an element with relative positioning and no floats to another div (as a child), you're changing the flow of the document since the parent div will stretch to fit or overflow causing a scrollbar, or overflow without a scrollbar if `overflow: hidden;` is set for instance.

With `position: absolute;` the element technically isn't in the document flow anymore but in the flow of the next `position: relative;` parent - it also doesn't care about other elements but the `position: relative;` parent **does** still care about where it is positioned.

This makes `position: absolute;` great for overlaying actions on top of other elements within the same div.

`position: fixed;` goes one step further and simply ignores **any** kind of positioning by any `position: relative;` or whatever element. `position: fixed;` binds your elements position to the *viewport* instead which allows you to have these fixed headers etc...

But because of this you can no longer 'contain' the div. You'll have to know it's height and apply a `height` or `min-height` on the container to create the spacing you need for that.

You're stating in a comment to a different answer that:

> Header's height is dynamic on every kind of viewports

I'm just going to assume you have different heights on different media queries here.

What you could then do is add the `min-height` or `height` property of the element which needs to contain your fixed navbar to those media queries to make it grow with the design but it'll always remain guesswork.

A lot of websites just  have a 2 size header, one for desktop which is a little bit higher and a responsive version - but they will always have a set height rather than something dynamic.

Usually overflowing menu's and other things and enhancing them with JS but I do not know your situation here so I'm not making any guesses about that.

Comment: Setting media queries on the parent element containing that fixed element might also solve this issue. I am trying multiple kind of approach now. Thx for your suggestion :)

Comment: @choz it will always remain guesswork as said but it could be 'good enough' or 'acceptable' instead of perfect to make a workable tradeff ;)

Answer (score 1):

A fixed element is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.You can use top, right, bottom, and left properties to place fixed element anywhere on view port.
You don't need clearfix for this.

But In this you don't need fixed layout, instead you should absolutely position your element relative to a parent div. See the code below for example.

```css
.navbar-float {
  background-color: #adadad;
  float: left;
}

.navbar-fixed {
  background-color: #dadada;
  position: absolute;
}

div.clearfix {
  border: 1px solid #adadad;
  padding: 4px;
  height:20px;;
  position:relative;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear:both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <nav class="navbar-float">
    Float
  </nav>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="clearfix">
  <nav class="navbar-fixed">
    Fixed
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm.. not my desired approach but I guess +1 coz there's no other way.. Ima give this a try and let c if this gonna mess my page up on viewport tests. Thx btw :)

Answer (score 0):

`fixed`, like `absolute`, will separate the element from the flow of the site. There is no way to use a fixed element to influence a parent.
I don't know what you try to accomplish, but this is the wrong way. Have you tried `fixed` on an element and then scroll? The element will stay in place on your viewport!

If you want to make space so that your nav does not overlap with your content, add a `div` with `height` or `min-height` as a kind of spacer.

Comment: Yes, I want to make space for my content so it doesn't overlap with my headers. The thing is, header's height is dynamic on every kind of viewports.